# "Einige Forschungen" or "manche Forschungen"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

I have seen that *some* can be used in a variety of ways. Is there a standard use of *some* that can be used on all occasions?

Comment: The question on "some" is quite broad. And we can't say whether "einige" or "manche" is better without context anyway.

Comment: Can you better connect your question body with your question title? Right now, you seem to be asking two separate questions.

Comment: Einige meiner Forschungen haben ergeben, dass es keine bevorzugte Übersetzung für 'some' gibt, vor allem nicht unabhängig vom Kontext.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Huh? Seit wann sind "Forschungen" rar? Und davon mal abgesehen, habe ich doch gar nichts über das Wort gesagt...

Comment: Ihr wollt Euch doch nicht mit Kafka anlegen? de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forschungen_eines_Hundes

Comment: @Em1: Nach weiterer Überlegung bin ich zu dem Schluss gekommen, dass *Forschungen* dann rar sind, wenn sie (zumindest implizit) mit einer konkreten Anzahl verknüpft sind, während *Forschungen* als Synonym zu *Forschung*, also als unspezifische Menge wissenschaftlicher Aktivitäten, durchaus vorkommt. Ich habe versucht, das in [meiner Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/27614/5999) etwas zu erläutern.

Comment: I don't have time to write a long answer, but I have two useful links about the use of _(etwas)/some/einige_: [link 1](http://courseware.nus.edu.sg/e-daf/cwm/la3201gr/e8/indef/indefetw.htm) and [link 2](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=1139115#followup11)

Comment: I came across the the word 'Forschungen' and 'einige Forschungen' but also 'manche Forschungsprojekte' Looking at the comments it would seem that 'Forschungen' is not universally accepted but this does not detract from the question I originally asked which was, Is the use of 'einige/manche' acceptable whatever the noun is? Or rather, is there a universal word for 'some'?

Comment: @JuliusTfruitfly: If the noun does not matter for your concern you should say so in your question. As it is now we can't answer the question without also taking "Forschung/en" into account. Suggestion for an [edit] resp. a new question: *Can we us "einige" or "manche" with uncountable plural subjects?*, then give some (*einige*) examples in your question body.

Answer (score 2):

Without any further context, my suggestions are:

- *Forschung*
- *ein Teil der Forschung*
- *manche/einige Forschungsprojekte* (see below)

Rationale:

As I mentioned in [a comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/einige-forschungen-or-manche-forschungen#comment66985_27603), the plural *Forschungen* sounds strange to me. After thinking about it some more, I think it is mainly because the expression *eine Forschung* does not make much sense. While the word *Forschung* on its own may be put into a plural form, *Forschung* as such still cannot be counted. The statements *Ich führe eine Forschung durch.*, *Ich führe zwei Forschungen durch.*, *Ich führe drei Forschungen durch.*, etc., are ill-defined as it is not clear what *eine Forschung* is supposed to be - as opposed to more specific words such as *eine Untersuchung*, or *eine Studie*.

Trying to generalize this, it seems to me that *Forschungen* sounds weird when it is implied to mean a specific number of ... "researches" (it doesn't really work much better in English, either, and I am tempted to write *research endeavours*, *research activities*, or similar instead of *researches*). That includes expressions like *fünf Forschungen*, but also expressions that imply a specific, but unknown number such as *viele Forschungen* or *einige Forschungen*.

In contrast, when the set of research activities is qualified by something other than a(n implicit) number, it sounds acceptable - *meine Forschungen*, *die Forschungen im Bereich der asiatischen Geschichte*, *Forschungen der Universität Tübingen*, etc., all sound ok. In this meaning, it should be noted that the plural form *Forschungen* is synonymous to the singular form *Forschung*, as both denote an unspecified amount of research activity.

Coming back to the question at hand, the OP wondered about the difference between *einige* and *manche*: These words can be distinguished based upon several aspects, all of which are rather subtle and thus not guaranteed to be picked up by a listener:

- *einige* might rather refer to more items than *manche*.
- *einige* sounds somewhat more formal than *manche*.
- As stated in [another answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/27610/5999), *manche* might lean a bit towards referring to a specific instead of arbitrary subset.

Comment: Ich halte es für schlechten Stil nicht die Frage zu beantworten, sondern Nebensächlichkeiten, an denen man sich dann hochzieht, um am Ende noch einen Satz zur eigentlichen Frage anzuhängen.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Frage ist zugegebenermaßen nicht sonderlich auskunftsfreudig. Letztendlich lässt sie sich auf "manche/einige Forschungen" reduzieren, womit "Forschungen" immerhin 50% des Informationsgehalts einnimmt. Aber im Ernst: Meine Antwort beginnt bereits mit Lösungsvorschlägen für die eigentliche Frage, und wieso diese nicht genau einer der zwei Antwortmöglichkeiten entsprechen, die sich der OP vorgestellt hat, wird eben auf Grundlage des geringen Kontexts aus der Frage erklärt. Dieser ist demnach offensichtlich nicht nebensächlich, sondern durchaus relevant.

Comment: Noch eine Frage: Welche Indizien sprechen für die Annahme 'einige might rather refer to more items than manche'? Wo ist hier der Informationsgehalt? Könnte, könnte aber auch nicht?

Comment: @userunknown Naja, ich würde auch sagen, dass 'einige' gerne auch im Sinne von 'viele' benutzt wird. Abhängig vom Kontext, der hier in der Frage leider fehlt, also kann auch die Antworr nicht konkret ausfallen

Comment: @suemi: Ein interessanter Vergleich von 'einige' mit ... - mit nix, irgendwie. Wie kann man da zum Schluss kommen, dass es einige, die es heiß mögen, zum Beispiel, mehr sind, als manche, die es heiß mögen? Wobei ich betonen will, dass ich glaube es sei umgekehrt. Ich sage, es gibt da keine Abstufung.

Comment: Würdest Du dich evtl. numerisch festlegen wollen, wenn man ein Dutzend hat, wieviele davon einige sein können, und wieviele manche?

Comment: @userunknown Jemand behauptet: "Es kann nicht stimmen, dass das Essen von zu vielen Keksen dumm macht!" Gegenargument: "Es gibt aber *einige* Studien, die dass bestätigen."

Comment: @suemi: Was soll dieser Satz jetzt belegen? Hätte man da nicht auch 'Es gibt aber manche Studien, die das belegen' sagen können?

Comment: @userunknown: Meinem persönlichen Sprachempfinden nach klingt "Es gibt aber manche Studien" nach einer verschwindend geringen Anzahl, der die große Mehrheit widerspricht (wobei "manche" in diesem Satz ungefähr synonym zu "einzelne" wäre), während "Es gibt einige Studien" eher nach einer nicht zu vernachlässigenden Anzahl klingt. Das mag aber regional unerschiedlich empfunden werden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Es gibt auch ein 'einiges', welches 'vieles' bedeutet: "Das wird uns aber einiges kosten!" Dem entspricht ein "so manches", nicht "manches" allein. In Deinen Sätzen wurde mir nicht deutlich, dass Du dieses 'einige' meinst - die Information muss dann im Kontext stecken.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt viele mögliche Übersetzungen für *some*.

Ob eine immer passt kann ich aus dem Stehgreif nicht sagen.

Ein Unterschied zwischen *einige* und *manche* sehe ich darin, ob die betreffenden Objekte unterscheidbar sind oder nicht.

> Einige Forschungen wurden von der DFG gefördert.
>   Manche Forschungen wurden von der DFG gefördert.

Hier kann man fragen *Welche denn?*.

> Gestern hatten wir noch 12 Löffel in der Schublade. Jetzt fehlen einige!

Wenn die Löffel noch neu sind, ohne individuelle Kratzspuren oder Verschmutzungen, kann man schlecht fragen *Welche denn?*. Dann passt m. E. nur *einige*, nicht *manche*.

Ich kann aber nicht sagen, ob das ein Regionalismus ist und man andernorts auch in diesen Fällen *manche* sagt. Eine Regel habe ich zur Unterscheidung jedenfalls nicht gelernt.

Da es hier zum bizarren Volkssport wurde, das Wort **Forschungen** zum unmöglichen Plural zu erklären, hier einige [Veröffentlichungen](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22forschungen%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=0wOXVpzmK4SEPuiZgegH) (das wird man wohl noch sagen dürfen) mit dem Wort *Forschungen* im Titel.

Jetzt ist auch der Duden wieder online. [Forschungen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Forschung) ist ohne jede Einschränkung Plural von Forschung.

Comment: The plural of Forschung sounds wrong.   I wouldn't say "Forschungen"  but "Forschungsprojekte".

Comment: Die Mehrzahl von Forschung ist Forschungen. Die Einzahl von Forschungsprojekte ist Forschungsprojekt. Wenn Duden seine Wartungsprojekte abgeschlossen hat lässt es sich sicher auch dort verifizieren, solange http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Forschung oder willst Du Dich mit Kafka anlegen? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forschungen_eines_Hundes

Comment: Ich würd mich hier dem [Wortschatz-Portal](wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de) bedienen. Ich will aber den erleben, der sagt "Forschung hat ergeben, dass"... :D